# comparing dates doesnt work

Tags: android, date

I've made this function that compares 3 dates but its not working and I cant figure out why. `data = 2013-02-10` and `data2= 2013-02-14`, `datateste` is the date of the system. it should appear an error alert but it doesn't

```
 void restricoes()  {
 Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

     try {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");

     java.util.Date strDate1 = sdf.parse(data);
     java.util.Date strDate2 = sdf.parse(data2);
     java.util.Date strDate = sdf.parse(datateste);




     if (strDate.before(strDate1) && strDate.after(strDate2)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "chupa boi",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data2,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), datateste,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            inputdata.setError("yipikaei");


     }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


if(checkEditText(inputdtestab) || checkEditText(quantidade))
{
    inputdtestab.setError("yipikaei");
    quantidade.setError("mudfukkerrr");
    btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
else{

     // ==========================================
     // make button visible.
     // use the method "setVisibility", not "setViewVisibility"
     // and "VISIBLE" in "View.VISIBLE" is in full cap:
     btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

so now instead of this i putted the code directly in the oncreate method and it works

try{

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date date1 = sdf.parse(datateste);
java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(data);

System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
    inputdata.setError("asa");
}else{
    System.out.println("How to get here?");
}

  }catch(ParseException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

but if change the data to not respect the if condition the error alert 
doesnt disappear

Answer (score 1):

Your date format uses this pattern `"yyyy/mm/dd"`. However, `mm` stands for minutes. If you need months, you need to uppercase it to `"yyyy/MM/dd"`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Furthermore, you're checking whether 2014/06/11 is both before 2013/2/10 and after 2013/2/14. That will obviously never be the case.

Comment: What are the values for `data`, `data2` and `datateste`? Looking at your question, it seems that you're logic for your dates is not right.

Comment: data 2012-02-10 data2 2012-02-12 datateste 2014-06-11

Comment: yeah lol it should be || instead of && but i dont thinkit will work let me see

Comment: it doesnt work i change && to || and doesnt show the error alert

Comment: Are you inputting dashes or slashes as separator?

Comment: Well, I guess it's time to fire up your debugger and step through your code, so you can pinpoint the location of the problem.

Comment: if i use this yyyy-MM-dd the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `data = "2013-02-10"`, but you seem to be parsing with the pattern `"yyyy/MM/dd"`.
Try with `"yyyy-MM-dd"` or change your input data.

Comment: that shuts down the program

Comment: Could you please link the stacktrace of the Logcat ?

Comment: 06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)

Comment: Somewhere in the rest of the stack trace (limited to 600chars here...) should be a call / an instruction of your code. Can you point out which one is it (the first one in the stack trace), that would lead you to spot the problem :)

Comment: 06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 11:10:32.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4551):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)

Comment: instead of puting the code in a function, i putted it directly on the oncreate method like this try{
  
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 java.util.Date date1 = sdf.parse(datateste);
 java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(data);

 System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
 System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

 if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
  inputdata.setError("asa");
 }else{
  System.out.println("How to get here?");
 }

}catch(ParseException ex){
 ex.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: and it works but when i change the date a before data the error doesnt disapear

Comment: Please be sure that `inputdata` is not null... Maybe the error is somewhere else in the code too.